# Cognos CASE statement

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I am new to Cognos and I'm writing a CASE statement and have two general questions.

1. Is there a more efficient way of writing this statement?
2. Can the different WHEN statements be grouped where they share a common
   description?

In the sample below several of the WHEN clause share a common THEN result i.e 'key tillage' or 'other crop production'.

Can you write the WHEN statement as:

```
WHEN ('Combo Primary Tillage','Disk Harrows','Field Cultivators') THEN ('Key Tillage')
```

Code CASE Sample

```
CASE([Class Long description])
WHEN('TR. 20<40') THEN ('Under 40')
WHEN('TR. 40<60') THEN ('40-59')
WHEN('TR. 60<100') THEN ('60-99')
WHEN('TR. 100<140') THEN ('100-139')
WHEN ('TR. 140<180') THEN ('140+')
WHEN ('TR. 180+') THEN ('140+')
WHEN('TR. 4WD') THEN ('4WD')
WHEN('CMB CAT 5') then ('Combines')
WHEN('CMB CAT 6') THEN('Combines')
WHEN('CMB CAT 7') THEN ('Combines')
WHEN('DISC MC') then ('Major Hay')
WHEN('SICKLE MC') THEN ('Major Hay')
WHEN('LARGE SQUARE BALER') THEN ('Major Hay')
WHEN('SMALL SQUARE BALER') THEN('Major Hay')
WHEN('ROUND BALER') THEN('Major Hay')
WHEN('SP WINDROWER') THEN('Major Hay')
WHEN('BALE THROWER') THEN('Other Hay')
WHEN('SP SPRAYERS') THEN('Sprayers')
WHEN('PLANTERS') THEN ('Planters')
WHEN('COMBO PRIMARY TILLAGE') THEN ('Key Tillage')
WHEN('DISK HARROWS') THEN('Key Tillage')
WHEN('FIELD CULTIVATORS') THEN ('Key Tillage')
WHEN('MIN PRIMARY TILLAGE') THEN('Key Tillage')
WHEN('VERTICAL SEEDBED TILLAGE') THEN ('Key Tillage')
WHEN('AIR DRILLS') THEN('Other Crop Production')
WHEN('FLOATER APPLICATORS') THEN('Other Crop Production')
WHEN('CHISEL PLOWS') THEN('Other Crop Production')
WHEN('CRUMBLERS') THEN('Other Crop Production')
WHEN('PULL TYPE SPRAYERS') THEN('Other Crop Production')
WHEN('AIR SYSTEMS') THEN('Other Crop Production')
WHEN('FLOATERS') THEN ('Other Crop Production')
ELSE ([Class Long description])
END
```

Answer (score 2):

No, can't. You can write it like

```
CASE
WHEN [Class Long description] in ('Combo Primary Tillage','Disk Harrows','Field Cultivators') THEN ('Key Tillage') 
WHEN [Class Long description] in ('AIR SYSTEMS','FLOATERS') THEN ('Other Crop Production') 
.....
END
```

But your approach is ineffective. You'd better create a table for it and join it to your original table.